# How to fetch url parameters from url sepearated by slash e.g http://myweb.com/example/12345/222/4444 I want to fetch 12345, 222, 4444 from above url

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs, pattern-matching

trying to get last parameters for further processing, but not able to separate them.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Maybe you should state the problem, show the error and ask a question???

Comment: Please put a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You try this one.**

```js
let test = (str)=>{
  return str.split('/').splice(3);
}


let str = "http://myweb.com/12345/222/4444";
let str1 = "http://myweb.com/12/22/4444";
let str2 = "http://myweb.com/123as45/222/4444";

console.log(test(str));
console.log(test(str1));
console.log(test(str2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using `split` function of JS after getting the `pathname` of the url.

```js
const url = 'http://myweb.com/12345/222/4444';
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;

const pathname = a.pathname.substring(1);
console.log(pathname.split('/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the URL parser:

```
new URL('http://myweb.com/12345/222/4444').pathname.substring(1).split('/')
```

You will get

```
["12345", "222", "4444"]
```